# Printing code symbol table failing with RuntimeError

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I updated the sorbet from v0.5.5569 to v0.5.5753. Before update I had 0 errors when running `bundle exec srb tc`, however after the update I got `Errors: 66`. I decided running `bundle exec srb rbi update` would help. But it failed with `RuntimeError`, here's the traceback:

```
Generating /tmp/d20200612-571-3e8xq8/reflection.rbi with 13952 modules and 216 aliases
Printing your code's symbol table into /tmp/d20200612-571-3e8xq8/from-source.json
Printing /tmp/d20200612-571-3e8xq8/reflection.rbi's symbol table into /tmp/d20200612-571-3e8xq8/reflection.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
    6: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sorbet-0.5.5753/bin/srb-rbi:237:in `<main>'
    5: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sorbet-0.5.5753/bin/srb-rbi:196:in `main'
    4: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sorbet-0.5.5753/bin/srb-rbi:121:in `init'
    3: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sorbet-0.5.5753/bin/srb-rbi:232:in `block in make_step'
    2: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sorbet-0.5.5753/lib/hidden-definition-finder.rb:38:in `main'
    1: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sorbet-0.5.5753/lib/hidden-definition-finder.rb:47:in `main'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sorbet-0.5.5753/lib/hidden-definition-finder.rb:151:in `write_constants': /tmp/d20200612-571-3e8xq8/reflection.rbi had unexpected errors. Check this file for a clue: /tmp/d20200612-571-3e8xq8/reflection.json.err (RuntimeError)
root@e50175f33244:/webapp# cat /tmp/d20200612-571-3e8xq8/reflection.json.err
/tmp/d20200612-571-3e8xq8/reflection.rbi:397297: Parent of class `Net::SSH::Transport::Kex::EcdhSHA2NistP256` redefined from `Net::SSH::Transport::Kex::Abstract5656` to `Net::SSH::Transport::Kex::DiffieHellmanGroup1SHA1` https://srb.help/5012
      397297 |class Net::SSH::Transport::Kex::EcdhSHA2NistP256 < Net::SSH::Transport::Kex::DiffieHellmanGroup1SHA1
                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can I fix it somehow or my only option is to stay on v0.5.5569 for now?

Comment: I can confirm the problem

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what was the problem but I think it's worth noting that we've eventually upgraded to `v0.5.5869` and no longer see this error.